# Atlas stone experience?

Tags: strength-training, olympic-weightlifting

My current strength routine consists of olympic-style squats, clean & jerks, snatches, clean pulls, that sort of thing.

I'm making steady progress, but considering adding some variation.  Does anybody have any experience with atlas stones?  The explosive hip extension and massive core involvement in movements such as the [stone to shoulder](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=857bGNXArZI) seem like they would have a great carryover to oly movements.

Has anybody found success with this strongman tool, specifically in relation to olympic lifts?  Are they a good supplemental exercise for olympic lifts?  What were your experiences?

Comment: I think being more specific would help attract better answers.

Comment: Yes, I think this needs to be edited to ask a specific question about Atlas stones. Right now, I read it as asking for general anecdotes which makes this not such a good fit for Stack Exchange.